# Splunk query output formating to JSON format

Tags: json, splunk, splunk-query

I have ingested some logs to Splunk which now looks like below when searching from search header.

`{\"EventID\":563662,\"EventType\":\"LogInspectionEvent\",\"HostAgentGUID\":\"11111111CE-7802-1111111-9E74-BD25B707865E\",\"HostAgentVersion\":\"12.0.0.967\",\"HostAssetValue\":1,\"HostCloudType\":\"amazon\",\"HostGUID\":\"1111111-08CF-4541-01333-11901F731111109\",\"HostGroupID\":71,\"HostGroupName\":\"private_subnet_ap-southeast-1a (subnet-03160)\",\"HostID\":85,\"HostInstanceID\":\"i-0665c\",\"HostLastIPUsed\":\"192.168.43.1\",\"HostOS\":\"Ubuntu Linux 18 (64 bit) (4.15.0-1051-aws)\",\"HostOwnerID\":\"1111112411\",\"HostSecurityPolicyID\":1,\"HostSecurityPolicyName\":\"Base Policy\",\"Hostname\":\"ec2-11-11-51-45.ap-southeast-3.compute.amazonaws.com (ls-ec2-as1-1b-datalos) [i-f661111148a3f6]\",\"LogDate\":\"2020-07-08T11:52:38.000Z\",\"OSSEC_Action\":\"\",\"OSSEC_Command\":\"\",\"OSSEC_Data\":\"\",\"OSSEC_Description\":\"Non standard syslog message (size too large)\",\"OSSEC_DestinationIP\":\"\",\"OSSEC_DestinationPort\":\"\",\"OSSEC_DestinationUser\":\"\",\"OSSEC_FullLog\":\"Jul  8 11:52:37 ip-172-96-50-2 amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[24969]:   \\\"Document\\\": \\\"{\\\\n    \\\\\\\"schemaVersion\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"2.0\\\\\\\",\\\\n    \\\\\\\"description\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Software Inventory Policy Document.\\\\\\\",\\\\n    \\\\\\\"parameters\\\\\\\": {\\\\n        \\\\\\\"applications\\\\\\\": {\\\\n            \\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"String\\\\\\\",\\\\n            \\\\\\\"default\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Enabled\\\\\\\",\\\\n            \\\\\\\"description\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"(Optional) Collect data for installed applications.\\\\\\\",\\\\n            \\\\\\\"allowedValues\\\\\\\": [\\\\n                \\\\\\\"Enabled\\\\\\\",\\\\n`

How can I format this correctly to show in JSON format when searing in searcher header. I'm pretty new to Splunk, hence have less idea on this.

My `file_monitor` > `props.conf` looks like below

```
[myapp:data:events]
pulldown_type=true
INDEXED_EXTRACTIONS= json
KV_MODE=none
category=Structured
description=data
disabled=false
TRUNCATE=88888
```

Comment: Does your data actually contain all those \\ ? Or just when you copy it into stackoverflow ?

Comment: It is actually contains these \\\ in my data

Comment: Is this being written to a file? If so, how? There is probably no need for all those \\, may need to SEDCMD them out

Comment: I’m sending this logs through http event collector. Logs writing to indexer cluster. But this is how it shows when search that index. My problem is why Splunk doesn’t shows the fields correctly. It not properly formatted.

Comment: How are you sending it through HEC? I assume the process there is adding all the additional \\. Splunk won't add \\ for no reason